# how to stop firebase dupicate data using android lifecircle method android

Tags: android

i have a main Activity class that calls fragments on BottomNaviagtion Bar

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        finishAffinity();

}

public boolean lunchFragment(Fragment fragment){
    if (fragment !=null){
        fragmentTransaction =getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fadein,R.anim.fadeout);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    Fragment fragment=null;
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.home:
            fragment=new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.chat:
            fragment=new ShopperFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.profile:
            fragment=new ProfileFragment();
            break;

        case R.id.menu:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"opened Dialoge",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
enter code here
    }
    return lunchFragment(fragment);
}
enter code here
```

when i navigate to my shopper Activity and go back to my Main Activity using my backButton it would replicate the data from firebase  which is on my onstart method in my fragment

```
public void LoadData(){
    final View view=getView();
    ShimmerRecyclerView=(ShimmerRecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.shimmer_recycler_view);
    lottieAnimationView=(LottieAnimationView)view.findViewById(R.id.noNetwork);
    noNetwork=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.noNetworktext);
    btnNetwork=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.loadNetwork);




    if (NetWorkState.isconnectedToNetwork(view.getContext())){
        //Invalidating
        ShimmerRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lottieAnimationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        noNetwork.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnNetwork.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        ShimmerRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(view.getContext(),1));
        ShimmerRecyclerView.showShimmerAdapter();
        childEventListener= refDb.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                if(dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().hasNext()){
                    ShopModel datamodels=dataSnapshot.getValue(ShopModel.class);
                    data.add(datamodels);
                }


                stores = new Stores(view.getContext(),data);
                ShimmerRecyclerView.setAdapter(stores);
                ShimmerRecyclerView.hideShimmerAdapter();
                stores.setStores(new Stores.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(long id) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), shopper.class));
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

//Todo check for network state and show a default screen if network isnt avaliable

```
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"No Network",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ShimmerRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lottieAnimationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        noNetwork.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnNetwork.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

i fixed that by calling onBackPressed on Shopper Acivity

Comment: now when i press home Button it still duplicate data
Can someone tell me how to stop data replication Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. 
I solved it with this code

```
dataRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         myArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); //Initialize your arraylist here
         for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
             try {
                   MyClass object = data.getValue(MyClass.class);
                    myArrayList.add(object);
                 }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }
             }
         }
});
```

Comment: i tried it it didnt work i just fixed it by adding the call method for the fragment in the onResume Method and it worked like magic